# Should I use TDD and BDD if my project is changing fast?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, tdd, integration-testing, bdd

I have my own little project I am creating using RoR, I plan it to have small-medium load.
With no doubt I started with BDD and TDD (Cucumber and RSpec to be exact, but I am also experienced with TestUnit), I like it but since it's my own project and it's a somewhat startup - I am changing many things in it, many requirements, many ideas how things should work and look. So it becomes too much time-consuming to always code it using BDD and TDD, even if I cover only common cases.
What should I do? Should I sacrifice BDD and TDD for productivity till I get to some point when I have a solid basis and it's time for production, and than I write tests?
Should I write them right now but as minimal as possible? Should I only write RSpec and forget about Cucumber for now? Or maybe just TestUnit to test model for now since it's the most important and everything else can change?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this a team effort or a one person project?

Comment: It may seem counterintuitive but I find having a good test suite helps me change fast

Answer (score 3):

This is not a politically correct answer and I am sure it will cause the purists to be upset.  Here goes: for a small, rapidly changing project it is better to just write the code and skip the TDD and BDD steps. Otherwise you will significantly delay completion. This is not a rule that should always be followed,  but if in your judgement you understand the project's requirements, then don't feel guilty about writing the code.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, if I'm iterating *just* to define functionality, design, implementation, etc. I tend to go light on the testing.

That said, once I'm *done* with that part, I generally throw those development spikes away, and move forward with a deliverable using T/BDD.

Answer (score 2):

It could be that using BDD/TDD might make you more productive. You say your requirements change often, perhaps it could be that changing/writing test cases and the like is more flexible/quick than writing the actual code then destroying it and writing new code every time your requirements change. Perhaps doing it this way serves as a sort of filter/layer through which to vet the changes you'd like to create. It might help give you an idea of whether or not things will work before you spend time implementing it. When you do implement it of course you have the benefits of TDD where you'll already have the testing suite to ensure correctness.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that since it's your project, you're really in the driver's seat. If you feel that the upsides for TDD/BDD are stronger than the upsides of more experimentation/quicker time to market, then I'd say stick with it. On the other hand, if you're really determining whether the project has legs or not and it may end up in the scrap yard then focusing on quicker learning in the short term may be a better option. I guess that's my way of suggesting that you determine your current goals for the project and align your practices with them.

While that didn't give a very concrete answer, as I think a bout it a bit, you may be able to do some higher level scenario tests to ensure that you're not breaking anything major in one of your quick feature changes, but forgo the full on TDD/BDD. My personal experience is that I feel more productive when practicing TDD because it helps me focus on solving one problem at a time and I find myself getting into a better rhythm.

Hope that helps!

Brandon

Comment: Hmm we have similarities in our answers. Tend to agree with you. +1 (also for the sweet avatar :p)

Answer (score 0):

> > So it becomes too much time-consuming to always code it using BDD and TDD, even if I cover only common cases.

I always seem to increase coding speed using TDD. Find 'stupid coding bugs' while executing tests and find the root cause factors faster then I would without my unit tests.

For BDD, if your requirements tend to overhaul I can imagine that you'd delay the tests for requirements until the ship sets sail in a more unified direction.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that you want to use TDD (maybe not BDD) precisely *because* requirements are changing so much.  TDD enables a design + codebase that is refactorable and as a result, easy to change.  Over the course of a project (even as small as a week or two in), you will actually move faster using TDD + Refactoring than if you didn't use it.